# How come I cannot calculate the running sum on the column I am ordering by?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

For example, I have this `Candidates` table:

```
    Candidates table:
+-------------+------------+--------+
| employee_id | experience | salary |
+-------------+------------+--------+
| 1           | Junior     | 10000  |
| 9           | Junior     | 10000  |
| 2           | Senior     | 20000  |
| 11          | Senior     | 20000  |
| 13          | Senior     | 50000  |
| 4           | Junior     | 40000  |
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

I just want to calculate the running sum on the salary for `Seniors`. This might be a brain fart on my part, but why won't this query work the way I expect it to:

```
select *
      , count(employee_id) over (order by salary)
      , sum(salary) over (order by salary)
from Candidates
where experience = 'Senior'
```

versus

```
select *
      , count(employee_id) over (order by salary, employee_id)
      , sum(salary) over (order by salary, employee_id)
from Candidates
where experience = 'Senior'
```

Why do I need to include the extra `employee_id` in my order by clause?

Answer (score 1):

Summing the salary over a window using `ORDER BY salary` won't behave the way you expect in the case of two or more records tied for the same salary.  In that case, as you have seen, the duplicate records will all have the same rolling sum value.  Actually, this is the query you seem to really want here:

```sql
SELECT *,
    COUNT(employee_id) OVER (ORDER BY employee_id) AS cnt,
    SUM(salary) OVER (ORDER BY employee_id) AS total_salary
FROM Candidates
WHERE experience = 'Senior';
```

The above takes the rolling sum of the salary using the `employee_id` as the order in which to take the sum.

Comment: but what if I also need the salary sorted in ascending order as well? Sorting by only `employee_id` wont work. The question is actually from https://leetcode.com/problems/the-number-of-seniors-and-juniors-to-join-the-company/

Comment: If you want to sort the result set by salary then maybe you need an `ORDER BY` clause.